# Limit URL's accessible over a SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel, socks-proxy

I have a server and I want to offer a tunnel through this server to some of my friends.
But I want to limit the sites they can access using this tunnel.

My plan was to create a user account without shell access, so that they can connect using ssh to have a tunneling socks proxy.

Is there a way to limit the sites a linux user can access?

It would be nice, if a URL based white-listing is possible, but IP based white-listing would also be okay.
Are there any other secure(!) software solutions to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any reason not to use [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) instead of SSH Tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

- using IPTables, only allow access to the IP address you want the user visit.
- give them a SQUID server they can use.

The SQUID server is probably the easiest option, given they will need an endpoint to connect to anyway. Using SQUID will give you the ability to block access to some sites, give access to others, and depending on how its setup, give you the ability to cache files also...